# how to find out where the error at in MYSQL version 5.7

Tags: mysql, pivot, mysql-error-1064

i have 3 tables like this

```
create table order_match
(
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
order_status_id int(10) not null
);

create table order_match_detail
(
 id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
 order_match_id int(10) not null,
 product_id int(10) NOT NULL
);

create table product
(
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
name varchar(255) not null
);

Insert into order_match (id, order_status_id)
select 1, 6 union all
select 2, 7 union all
select 3, 6 union all
select 4, 6;

Insert into order_match_detail (id, order_match_id, product_id)
select 1, 1, 147  union all
select 2, 2, 148 union all
select 3, 3, 147 union all
select 4, 4, 149 union all
select 5, 4, 147;

Insert into product (id, name)
select 147, 'orange' union all
select 148, 'carrot' union all
select 149, 'Apple';
```

with `order_match.id = order_match_detail.order_match_id`
and `order_match_detail.product_id = product.id`

i want to make the data where `order_status_id` not in 7 then it's success transaction and from that success transaction, if the transaction buy apple, then the column of apple contain `1` else if not buying, then `0` and this is my expected results, i want to make this data to analyze in

```
 id (in order_match)    |    Orange  |  Carrot  |   Apple
    
    1                           1            0           0
    3                           1            0           0
    4                           1            0           1
```

**the real problem is** i've just fit in whether the version of mysql, and fit in with the same data type for every table, i dont really know why in my fiddle it's work, but on mysql it's contain

> error code :1064.you have an error in your sql syntax near ' '' at
> line 1

this is my [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDe3oQ3VdtfS5QDokieHN4/7)

**new UPDATE**
after take a look with the data, i assume the product name in field have format that cant be acceted mysql. so i've made the new query like this

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when name = ''',
      name,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      concat('product', id)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from product;

SET @sql1 = CONCAT('SELECT omd.order_match_id, ', @sql, ' from order_match_detail omd
left join order_match om
  on omd.order_match_id = om.id
left join product p
  on omd.product_id = p.id
where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by omd.order_match_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This is the new [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDe3oQ3VdtfS5QDokieHN4/9)

but in my new mysql it's said

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'from order_match_detail omd left join order_match
> om   on omd.order_match_id = o' at line 1

Comment: with out seeing your real data at least as real as it can get, you are the only one that can help. But look  first _@sql  and what is the result before the concat, when all seems to be ok with quotes double quotes etc you get the the _@sql and post this query here

Comment: Do you have a product name with a `'` character?

Comment: after i check it, my real data contain some "/" and any other character who seems cant accept with this query

Comment: Reconsider your approach and use an application language to do this rather than attempting a pivot.

Comment: @danblack can you give me a suggest for the solution

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I suggest you select sql1 copy the result and see if that runs..

Comment: sorry im bad in english, what do you mean in select sql1 copy the result?